# AngularJS: how can I get $location.path to template

Tags: angularjs

I need current path from url in template (content of $location.path). But not via controller, because I have a lot of controllers (and I do not want to duplicate declaration of `$scope.currentUrl = $location.path;`). Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

AngularJS template can only see what is available in a scope so you will need somehow to put $location service in a scope. There is one scope that is always available in AngularJS application called $rootScope so it could be use for your use-case.

What you could do is to use run() method of a module to expose $location in the $rootScope:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []).run(function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.location = $location;
});
```

this would make 'location' available in all templates so later on you could do in your template:

```
Current path: {{location.path()}}
```

Comment: In a directive template that has its own scope, you need to use `Current path: {{$parent.location.path()}}`

Comment: It's a good habit to use `{{ $root.location.xxx }}` since any directive with an isolate scope wouldn't have access to it via the shorthand method and the `$parent.location` is unreliable depending on your scope depth. `$root` always works.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use the more semantic and versatile [ui-router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/), then in the controller, [retrieve the current state](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1482), and store it on the `$scope`:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', function MyCtrl($scope, $state) {
  $scope.state = $state.current.name;
  ...
}
```

Comment: I think the downvotes are perhaps because even if OP were using ui-router (and this issue alone is hardly reason enough to migrate) this returns the state name, which is usually completely different than the URL's path (which will also include any dynamic params). For example, in my application, for the path: "/graphs/56ce3/edit" your code returns the name of the state, "edit.graph". In the words of Hyperbole and a Half "No, see, that solution is for a different problem than the one I have." :)

Comment: For future readers of this thread using ui-router, you probably want `$state.href($state.current)`, not `$state.current.name`.