# Is it possible to get the current $location in a directive in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Something along the lines of: `link: function($scope, element, attrs, $location) {`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the declaration of the directive, inject the location service.

```
app.directive('myDirective', ['$location', function($location) {

 return {
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
   // path() and url() can be used as getters or setters
   console.log($location.url());
   console.log($location.path());
  }
 };
}]);
```

If you are attempting to get the current location, use `location.path()` or, alternatively, use the `$route` service.

Information on both:

1. [$route Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)
2. [$location Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

Comment: The location doesn't update when I change to another page however.

Comment: Are you attempting to get the location they are on using the location service?

Comment: Yes please. That's the goal

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide some additional hints. You need to use either the location service or path service but it depends on what you want from the route.

Comment: I want the path, specifically `$location.path()`, but that's not updating when I switch pages.

Comment: Is the page switch simply a change in parameter? I.e /users/1 and /users/2? If so you need to watch the route service and look for more granular changes in the parameters.

Comment: The page switch is more than just a change in parameter. It goes from `/page1` to `/page2`

Comment: You can't actually reference `$location` this way. You need to follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/11935803/633107 and put it in the `$rootScope`, then access it via `scope.$root.location` in your directive.

Answer (score 3):

thought injecting service into directive it still gets undefined into link function,
for that you need to use

```
location.hash = "#/path_name";
```

in link function it will work