# how to pass url using button click event in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want passing  URL through button click event into my directive using angularjs.my task is to click on button the new html page will be displayed on browser so for this i am doing following example.
Test.html:

```
<test1>
    <button  ng-click="click('/sample.html')">Go</button> 
</test1>
```

Test.js:

```
 app.directive('test1', function() {
        function compile(scope, element, attributes) {
         return{
             post:function(scope, element, iAttrs,location) {
                 scope.click=function(path)
                 {  
                 location.path(path );
                 };
             }
         };
        }

        return({
            compile: compile,
            restrict: 'AE',

        });

    });
```

the path will be getting in click function but i want to display sample.html on browser so please suggest me how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: is click function getting called?

Comment: yes its called for exp in alert(path);in alert palce sample.html will be dispaled also

Comment: I think this is the answer to your question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139555/is-it-possible-to-get-the-current-location-in-a-directive-in-angular-js . You need to inject $location from directive instead of post function. app.directive('test1', ['$location', function(location){

Comment: i am using app.directive('test1', ['$location', function(location) but it is not redirect to sample.html page .