# To get Current location in angular Js

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I have an angular js app in which I have an option like Current location.
Clicking this option, we should be able to see our current location, just the location name or the google map of the location.
Can any body help with the custom directive to be used in this case.
The app is transformed to android using PhoneGap.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: its a huge application i need to create a page to show this current location.
just need the custom directive to use.

Comment: Similar Stack....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139555/is-it-possible-to-get-the-current-location-in-a-directive-in-angular-js

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Nope @yjs. it's not angular `$location`. It is **HTML5 Geolocation**.

Answer (score 6):

No body will write whole directive for you. Helping you to get current location from browser. Showing current location on the MAP is your's job!

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        //browser does not support geolocation
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    var latitude =  position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude; 
}
```

[HTML5 Geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)

Comment: welcome. Now you can accept this answer. @AswinKallikadavil