# Parent DOM manipulation by child?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have a setup something like the following:

```
<nav>
    <li>
        <a someClassToggleDirective>Menu 1</a> <!-- This anchor element toggle determines if ul.sub-menu should be expanded (displayed) -->
        <ul class="sub-menu">   <!-- This is displayed when it's first sibling 'a' has 'open' class -->
            <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="childComp1">Child Component 1</a></li>
            <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="childComp2">Child Component 2</a></li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a someClassToggleDirective>...</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>
    ...
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

To load any component, a `li` item is clicked which then expands it's sub menu `ul`. Clicking on one of the sub-menu items loads the corresponding component in `<router-outlet></outlet>` and set the sub-menu item as *active*. The route would be then `[root]/childComp1` for example. But if I directly navigate to `[root]/childComp1` using browser's address bar, the component will be loaded but the parent `ul` of the active child component is not expanded.

So, how do I get it expanded? For a sub menu (`ul`) to expand, I need to add a class `open` to its sibling `a`. How do I do this? A way that comes to my mind is using `this.router.url` to determine the component and based on the route name expand the corresponding `sub-menu`. But I feel this is not the best way to do this. Is there any better way? I want to avoid any third-party libraries like jQuery.

Comment: you need to add a directive to ul element, and then inject $location into the directibe to get the current location, if it matches the corresponding ul element, then we need to add the class 'open'. it will be a simple if loop, refer: [directive get location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139555/is-it-possible-to-get-the-current-location-in-a-directive-in-angular-js)

Comment: @NarenMurali I'm trying to add a directive to `li`. Inside `li` is another submenu `ul` whose one of `li`s will have `active` class given by `[routerLinkActive]` directive. So, inside the directive, I want to check if any of `li`s of `ul` inside the current `li` has a `active` class. If the case is so, the `li` will have a `open` class. Now, what event will I bind `@HostListener` to? Binding on `load` won't work because all views won't be initialized by then. And how will I check if the child `li` has `active` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@ContentChildren` decorator to get all instances of `RouterLinkActive` inside submenu. And detect whether there is active links.

For example, you can create directive, which keeps list of links. And on every route change toggle `expand` prop.

**Directive**

```js
import {Directive, HostListener, HostBinding, ContentChildren, QueryList} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, RouterLinkActive, NavigationEnd} from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Directive({ selector: '[listToggle]' })
export class ListToggleDirective {

  // Collect RouterLinkActive instances
  @ContentChildren(RouterLinkActive) links: QueryList<RouterLinkActive>;

  // If expand=true - show submenu
  @HostBinding('class.expand')
  expand: boolean;

  routerSub: Subscription;

  constructor(private router: Router) {

  }


  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    // Detect if there is active links
    this.routerSub = this.router.events
      .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .subscribe(() => this.detectActiveLink());
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.routerSub) {
      this.routerSub.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  detectActiveLink(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const hasActive = this.links.some(link => link.isActive);
      this.expand = hasActive;
    });
  }

}
```

**Usage**

```html
<ul>
    <li listToggle>
        <a>Open menu 1</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <a routerLink="/cmp1" routerLinkActive="active">cmp1</a>
            <a routerLink="/cmp2" routerLinkActive="active">cmp2</a>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li listToggle>
        <a>Open menu 2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <a routerLink="/cmp3" routerLinkActive="active">cmp3</a>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Styles**

```css
li[listtoggle] {
    &.expand .sub-menu {
        display: block;
    }
    .sub-menu {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps